# Make unicode from variable containing QString

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt

I have QPlainTextEdit field with data containing national characters (iso-8859-2).

```
tmp = self.ui.field.toPlainText() (QString type)
```

When I do:

```
tmp = unicode(tmp, 'iso-8859-2')
```

I get question marks instead of national characters. How can I convert properly the data in QPlainTextEdit field to unicode?

Comment: AFAIK `QString` uses UTF-16, so you might try that.

Comment: Thanks for hint - I will try that later and give feedback.
BTW thx for modyfing post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was said QPlainTextEdit.toPlainText() returns QString which should be UTF-16, whereas unicode() constructor expects a byte string. Below is a small example:

```
tmp = self.field.toPlainText()
print 'field.toPlainText: ', tmp

codec0 = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-16");
codec1 = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("ISO 8859-2");  

print 'UTF-16: ', unicode(codec0.fromUnicode(tmp), 'UTF-16')
print 'ISO 8859-2: ', unicode(codec1.fromUnicode(tmp), 'ISO 8859-2')
```

this code produces following output:

> field.toPlainText:  test ÖÄ это
>   китайский: 最主要的
>
> UTF-16:  test ÖÄ это китайский: 最主要的
>
> ISO 8859-2:  test ÖÄ ??? ?????????:
>   ????

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Works fine. But I've got an additional question - let's assume that tmp variable (iso 8859-2) has to be sent in encoded form. Will b64encode(tmp) and later b64decode(tmp) work properly with national characters? Seems a lot of encoding/decoding for me but I sort of need that and it was always painful experience.

Comment: hmm.. if protocols\media you're working with is designed to deal with textured data you need to use base64 encoding. I don't think there are any other ways possible there